Azure AD App Registration unable to change "Who can consent"
I'm creating a MSAL web API using instructions here. When following the instructions for "Expose the API", I am not able to adhere to step b. (For Who Can consent, ensure the Admins and users option is selected).
1. Under Manage, select Expose an API > Add a scope. Accept the proposed Application ID URI (api://{clientId}) by selecting Save and continue. The {clientId} is the value recorded from the Overview page. Then enter the following information:
  a. For Scope name, enter Forecast.Read.
  b. For Who can consent, ensure that the Admins and users option is selected.
  c. In the Admin consent display name box, enter Read forecast data.
  d. In the Admin consent description box, enter Allows the application to read weather forecast data.
  e. In the User consent display name box, enter Read forecast data.
  f. In the User consent description box, enter Allows the application to read weather forecast data.
  g. Ensure that the State is set to Enabled.

The option doesn't even show up on the screen.
Note this app registration is NOT in a B2C tenant. The second picture below shows what I see when I search Azure B2C and click the link, there are no applications registered.


Later steps fail and I think it's because of this. The instructions are fairly recent (4/24/2024), but following them step by step doesn't work. What is missing?

Could you check and confirm what tenant you currently logged in? If it's Azure AD B2C tenant, you won't be having that option.

If you registered application in Azure AD B2C tenant and exposed an API, it won't be having Admins and users option like this:

For that, you need to switch to normal Microsoft Entra ID tenant and register application in it that have Admins and users option when exposed an API:

If your use case is to expose an API in Azure AD B2C tenant, you can follow this MS Document that won't support user consent option by default.
Here is what I see when following instructions here when I click on Microsoft Entra ID in the menu.


I added a screenshot to the post showing I am not in a B2C tenant.
BUT my options in the left menu look like your B2C tenant options. I'm missing "App Roles" and "Roles and administrator" options.

But all your portal images look like B2C tenant. Can you type Azure AD B2C in search bar and check what you are getting by clicking it. Please add that Portal image by editing your question. If it has User flows option, then it's Azure AD B2C tenant. While registering new application, you can check supported account type options. If it has 3 options only and 3rd one is account type supporting user flows, then it is Azure AD B2C tenant.

I added a screenshot after searching Azure AD B2C. As you can see there are no applications registered under B2C. When I initially created this it was B2C, but then I deleted the resource and recreated it. I wonder if there is a bug where it still has B2C properties. Can you provide instructions to create a tenant that is NOT B2C? I'll try creating a new tenant with a different name. Thank you.

Check if this helps https://docs.azure.cn/en-us/entra/fundamentals/create-new-tenant#create-a-new-tenant-for-your-organization

Please include how you created Azure account? Have you opted for free trial subscription?

I added a screenshot for what I see when I go to Microsoft Entra ID in the left navigation menu. I do not have an option for Identity -> Overview -> Manage Tenants. I do have Manage -> App registrations. I don't remember how I created my azure account, I've had it for many years.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

You can create app registration in this Default Directory tenant and try exposing an API in it and check if you can see Admins and users consent option or not.
